# Calculate 95th Pencentile Of Data Using PERCENTILE_CONT & PERCENTILE_DISC

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have loaded SQL Server trace to a table with following fields `StartTime`, `Duration`, `Object_name`, `DatabaseID`, `HostName` and `ApplicationName`.

How to compute 95th percentile of average duration grouping by `hour`, `Object_name`, `DatabaseID`, `HostName` and `ApplicationName`?

Comment: What's the data type for duration? Can you add some sample data? Is there any attempt to check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to know the answer to your question.  It is something like this:

```
select avg(duration) as avg_duration,
       percentile_cont(0.95) within group (order by avg(duration)) over () as percentile_95
from t
group by hour, Object_name, DatabaseID, HostName, ApplicationName;
```

Note:  this puts the value on each row.  I would be inclined to get a single value using:

```
select top (1) percentile_cont(0.95) within group (order by avg_duration) over () as percentile_95
from (select avg(duration) as avg_duration,
             percentile_cont(0.95) over (order by avg(duration)) as percentile_95
      from t
      group by hour, Object_name, DatabaseID, HostName, ApplicationName
     ) t;
```

Comment: PERCENTILE_CONT ( numeric_literal )   
    WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY order_by_expression [ ASC | DESC ] )  
    OVER ( [ <partition_by_clause> ] )     i think your missing clause here @gordon

Comment: yes, it returns this ...
Msg 10754, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
The function 'percentile_cont' must have a WITHIN GROUP clause.